# When reading from MYSQL only displays $_SESSION["ID"];

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

I am trying to retrieve the user's username form the database. I am searching the user from `$_SESSION["ID"]`, which is set after the user successfully logs into the site.

When I am trying to display the username it displays the `$_SESSION["ID"]`.

```
 <?php
include ("db_safe.php");

$user_ID = $_SESSION["ID"];

$stmt_user_profile = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_ID LIKE :user");
$stmt_user_profile->bindValue(':user', $user_ID);
$stmt_user_profile->execute();

$result_user_profile = $stmt_user_profile->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result_user_profile as $user_info){
    $profile_username = $user_info["username"];
    $profile_email = $user_info["email"];
}
?>

<h3>Hello <?php echo $profile_username; ?> </h3>
```

Do you have any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06mrI.jpg)
[MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4gQt.jpg)

Comment: Have you put session_start(); in the start of the script?

Comment: Why are you using LIKE ? I think = would be better  in where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Please try below code and I hope this will help you.

```
<?php
include ("db_safe.php");
$user_ID = $_SESSION["ID"];
$stmt_user_profile = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_ID LIKE ?");
$stmt_user_profile->execute(array($user_ID));
$allusers = $stmt_user_profile->fetchAll();

foreach ($allusers as $user)
{
     $profile_username = $user["username"];
     $profile_email = $user["email"];
}

?>

<h3>Hello <?php echo $profile_username; ?> </h3>
```

Comment: Always welcome. If it worked then please give this answer positive vote @Vani Kalapciev.

Comment: can you explain this? I really want to know how is this solving the problem

Comment: Actually @VaniKalapciev , issue was regarding to bindParam , sometimes the bindParam needs strict value that it needs as per its structure for query execution.

The solution that I made is using PDO but not with bindparam , it is just taking the parameters in array and execute so no concept of binding in that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$stmt_user_profile->bindParam(':user', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

instead of **bindValue**.